# Submitting form is resetting city dropDown javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, debugging

i made two dynamic dropdown list `State and city`

City dropdown will depend of selected option of state

problem is when all is good and okay to submit .it resets the city drop down 
and does not submit

javascript code for making those dynamic drop down is

these function are onchange events

```
    // remove all previous options 
    function removeOptions(selectbox) {
        for (let i = selectbox.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            selectbox.remove(i);
        }
    }
    // function to make city drop down according to selected state
    function cityFunction(){
    // get input value and text
    const stateobj = document.getElementById('stateDropDown');
    const valueState = stateobj.options[stateobj.selectedIndex].text;
    const selectedOption = stateobj.options[stateobj.selectedIndex].value;

    // making required arrays 

    let sindhArray = [ 'Select City', 'Karachi', 'Hyderabad', 'Mirpur khas', 'Sukkhar', 'Shikarpur' ];
    let KhyberArray = [ 'Select City', 'gilgit', 'Qalat', 'Balakoot', 'Sawat', 'Peshwar' ];
    let punjabArray = [ 'Select City', 'Lahore', 'Fasialabad', 'Qasoor', 'SheikhuPura', 'Gujrat' ];
    let balochArray = [ 'Select City', 'Quetta', 'Chaman', 'Khuzdar', 'Turbat', 'Gawdar' ];


    // if value is punjab or any select cities according to that state
    if (valueState == 'Punjab') {
    // removing all previous present options 
        removeOptions(document.getElementById('cityDropDown'));

        let cityD = document.querySelector('#cityDropDown');
        let index = 0;

        for (let ele of punjabArray) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = index;
            opt.innerHTML = ele; // whatever property it has
            document.getElementById('cityDropDown').value = cityD.appendChild(opt);

            index++;
        }
    }
    if (valueState == 'Sindh') {
        removeOptions(document.getElementById('cityDropDown'));
        let cityD = document.querySelector('#cityDropDown');
        let index = 0;

        for (let ele of sindhArray) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = index;
            opt.innerHTML = ele; // whatever property it has

            document.getElementById('cityDropDown').value = cityD.appendChild(opt);

            index++;
        }
    }
    if (valueState == 'Balochistan') {
        removeOptions(document.getElementById('cityDropDown'));

        let cityD = document.querySelector('#cityDropDown');
        let index = 0;

        for (let ele of balochArray) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = index;
            opt.innerHTML = ele; // whatever property it has

            document.getElementById('cityDropDown').value = cityD.appendChild(opt);

            index++;
        }
    }

    if (valueState == 'khyber Pakhtunkhwa') {
        removeOptions(document.getElementById('cityDropDown'));

        let cityD = document.getElementById('cityDropDown');

        let index = 0;

        for (let ele of KhyberArray) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = index;
            opt.innerHTML = ele; // whatever property it has

            document.getElementById('cityDropDown').value = cityD.appendChild(opt);
    index++;
        }
    }
    }
```

for city form validation onchange event is

```
function cityDown() {
    const cityObj = document.getElementById('cityDropDown');
    const cityText = cityObj.options[cityObj.selectedIndex].text;

    const valueOfCity = cityObj.options[cityObj.selectedIndex].value;

    let citiesArray = [
        'Quetta',
        'Chaman',
        'Khuzdar',
        'Turbat',
        'Gawdar',
        'Lahore',
        'Fasialabad',
        'Qasoor',
        'SheikhuPura',
        'Gujrat',
        'gilgit',
        'Qalat',
        'Balakoot',
        'Sawat',
        'Peshwar',
        'Karachi',
        'Hyderabad',
        'Mirpur khas',
        'Sukkhar',
        'Shikarpur'
    ];

    if ( valueOfCity == 0) {
        document.getElementById('cityErr').innerText = 'City is required';
        document.getElementById('cityDropDown').focus();
        return valueOfCity;
    }
    if (citiesArray.indexOf(cityText) < 0) {
        document.getElementById('cityErr').innerText = 'Select City';
        document.getElementById('cityDropDown').focus();
        return valueOfCity;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('cityErr').innerText = '';
        return valueOfCity;
    };
}
```

main function is

```
        // validation f0rm function

        function validateForm() {
            // creating variable then sanitize them

            isTrueorFalse = false;
        document.getElementById('Address').disabled = isTrueorFalse;
            document.getElementById('stateDropDown').disabled = isTrueorFalse;
            document.getElementById('stateDropDown').style.background = '#FFF';
            document.getElementById('cityDropDown').disabled = isTrueorFalse;
            document.getElementById('cityDropDown').style.background = '#FFF';
            const stateVal = stateDrag();
            const cityV = cityDown();
            const userAddress = form.Address.value;
            //States must not be unselected
            if (stateVal == 0 || stateVal == '') {
                document.getElementById('stateErr').innerText = 'State is required.';
                document.getElementById('stateDropDown').focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (stateVal < 0) {
                document.getElementById('stateErr').innerText = 'State is required.';
                document.getElementById('stateDropDown').focus();
                return false;
            }

            document.getElementById('addressErr').innerText = '';
            document.getElementById('cityDropDown').focus();
        console.log(cityV);
            if (cityV == 0 || cityV == '') {
                document.getElementById('cityErr').innerText = 'State is required.';
                document.getElementById('cityDropDown').focus();
                return false;

    }


            document.getElementById('cityErr').innerText = '';
        document.getElementById('signupForm').submit();
}
```

here that demo

https://jsbin.com/jeguwakolo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Your question should have all the code (but nothing more than necessary) to reproduce the problem. It should not be behind a link. Yet, I checked there, and saw no code for `validateForm`, yet it is referenced in the `onsubmit` attribute.

Comment: @trincot forgive this newbie soul going to add it just now

Comment: a first thing I noticed is that the citiesArray array is not passed to the form dropdown. Not sure if this is the cause of the submit not working, but I would start from that.

Comment: @CarmineTambascia just added that

Comment: @Maria, another small thing I noted, but that hasn't  to do with your issue, is that I would put placeholder=city is required" inside the small tag, that can be overridded by the user.

Comment: it was demanded ..Thats y i included that again in validation function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onsubmit was calling that function again and was resetting the city dropdown.

To solve this i just removed that function from stateDrag() and 
in html i did this

```
<select oninput ="return stateDrag()" onchange="return cityFunction()">
```

after this i didnt get same problem and scripting was working fine thank you for everyone